# How to hold "invisible" values and get them using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I run a music blog using WordPress and I have a custom music player for it. Every time a post has a song attached to it, I want to create a way to hold that information and later access custom variables. What I need is something along the lines of...

```
<div class="playable" 
     title="Song Title" 
     mp3="URL" 
     soundcloudLink="https://soundcloud.com/cashcash/take-me-home-jordy-dazz">
</div>
```

Then in my `$(document).ready()` function I would need a function that finds all objects of class "playable" and be able to access the title tag, mp3 tag, soundcloudLink tag, etc.

Any easy suggestions?

Comment: So, did what you said not work? What went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

> 3.2.3.9 Embedding custom non-visible data with the data-* attributes
>
> A custom data attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name starts with the string "data-", has at least one character after the hyphen, is XML-compatible, and contains no uppercase ASCII letters.
>
> All attribute names on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase letters doesn't affect such documents.
>
> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.
>
> These attributes are not intended for use by software that is independent of the site that uses the attributes.

E.g., they always pass validation, and they're only for your use.

So for instance:

```
<div class = "playable"
     title = "Song Title"
     data-mp3 = "URL"
     data-soundcloudLink = "https://soundcloud.com/cashcash/take-me-home-jordy-dazz"
></div>
```

When you need to access that information, you get a jQuery object for the `div`, and then use [`attr("data-mp3")`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) or [`data("mp3")`](http://api.jquery.com/data) to access it. (Or without jQuery, get the `HTMLDivElement` and use `getAttribute`.) Note that I haven't changed `title`. [`title`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-title) is a valid attribute, and accessible via `.prop("title")` on jQuery instances or via `.title` on DOM elements.

Note that `data` is assymetrical: It *reads* from `data-*` attributes for initialization, but doesn't *write* to them.

Comment: Yes this looks like what I need. Do you know how to return an array of every div with `class = "playable"` and iterate through them and pass values to my already pre-defined JavaScript function `add_song(title, mp3, soundcloudLink)`?

Comment: @jas7457: Since you're using jQuery: `$(".playable").each(function() { add_song(this.title, this.getAttribute("data-mp3"), this.getAttribute("data-soundcloudLink")); });` or `$(".playable").each(function() { var $this = $(this); add_song(this.title, $this.attr("data-mp3"), $this.attr("data-soundcloudLink")); });`

Comment: You, sir, are a god amongst men.

Comment: @jas7457: LOL! You clearly haven't met me. :-) You're very kind, and very welcome.

Comment: Remember to replace the `"` in attribute values(song title, artist, etc) with `&quot;` while generating the html.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the data- attribute which can easily be retrieved by .data() method.

HTML:

```
<div id="thing" data-title="Keine Lust" data-file="keine_lust.mp3"></div>
```

JQuery

```
var song_title = $("#thing").data("title");
var song_file = $("#thing").data("file");
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, but I will have to do it with multiple instances, not just a single ID. This is why I was thinking of somehow definining a class, but I don't know how to use JavaScript or jQuery to return an array that has ALL the elements of that class and be able to iterate through them to pass these values to my custom JavaScript function that I already have defined as `add_song(title, mp3, soundcloud);`

Comment: Fixed some errors in your post, and I'd kindly suggest this approach: http://jsbin.com/aqihef/2/edit

Comment: @jas7457 Well a class can be changed for the id but you will need to keep track of the index of the instance you are getting the data from.

Comment: Remember to replace the `"` in attribute values(song title, artist, etc) with `&quot;`. otherwise it will break your html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.hasClass()` jquery function to display the attributes of the elements with that class. Add an ID to the element like in this case I added test.. here is how to alert them.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
var className = $('#test').hasClass('playable')
    if( className ){

        var url = $('#test').attr('soundcloudLink');
        var title = $('#test').attr('title');

        document.write(title);
        document.write(url);
    }


});
```

This one displays the soundcloud link and the title if the element has the class playable. here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uprosoft/2Frk3/3/